# Ant ran from MyEclipse not using the "default" JRE

Tags: eclipse, ant, myeclipse

I am working as a contractor, and they are using MyEclipse 10.0 with Ant to do builds.  Its been a LONG time since I used Ant as the build tool, as I have primarily been on Maven for some time.

Their source are broken into multiple projects, and each links back to a common project that has a commone build.xml that is imported by each project's build.xml.  The ant script is used to WAR the app and do deployments both locally and on their Test environment using WebLogic's java-based deployment tools.  They are using WebLogic 9.2, which, from what I read, has issues with JDK 1.6 and higher.  I have set the 1.5 JDK/JRE as the default inside MyEclipse in Preferences->Installed JREs.

For all the projects, when I launch the Ant target from within Eclipse it runs under the 1.5 JDK/JRE I set as the default.  But for this one project it seems to insist on running under the 1.6 JDK that ships as part of MyEclipse 10.  If I right-click on the Ant build in the Ant view/tab and look at the properties for the Run Configuration (right click, Run As->External Tool Configuration...), the JRE selected shows the 1.5 JDK/JRE.  But alas, when I run it it STILL is running under the 1.6 JDK.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, even though Eclipse was reporing the JDK set to 1.5, it wasn't.  I went into Run As->External Tools..., set it to 1.6, saved, then set it back to 1.5...poof!  now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Search your Ant files for the string [`fork`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html). It might be that one of the Ant tasks itself starts a new VM.